# Connecting Mainframe MQ manager from Microfocus Enterprise Server

Tags: mqtt, ibm-mq, mainframe, microfocus

I have a requirement where I need to get/put data from the queue at Mainframe manager. I know that I need to define local queue at mainframe side but I am not sure how can we defined queue on mainframe for Microfocus.

Please help

I have defined XAR and Listner for microfocus enterprise server but not sure about all the fields. I know that it would be server and client configuration. I am expecting if someone has implemented this before, please help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already for the "XAR and Listner", so we can be sure to understand exactly your requirements. We might be able to help with the fields you are unsure about. I would expect there to be no difference in how you DEFINE the local queue on the mainframe queue manager whether you plan to use it from a Microfocus application or any other application. I would also expect client and server. So I would expect you to have to DEFINE a CHANNEL of TYPE(SVRCONN) on the mainframe queue manager too.